# Expectation for MLE of normal distribution

Tags: statistics

The picture below is computing expectation of sigma for normal distribution. However, I don't quite understand how does the part underscored by green line. I thought it should be green note on the right side. Can anybody help me with my confusion?

[Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPhKT.png)

Comment: This result for the mean sample variance is [much more general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) than the Normal distribution's MLE.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_iX_i$, $$E\bar{X}^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{ij}EX_iX_j=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{ij}\left(\mu^2+\sigma^2\delta_{ij}\right)=\mu^2+\frac{\sigma^2}{n}.$$